# Find all group of neighbors with a constraint weight

Tags: nearest-neighbour

Forgive if this seems like a repeated question. However, I couldn't find a specific algorithm to my needs.

I have nodes that have weights with each other. I want to find all unique groups of nodes, with the constraint that every node in the group has a weight with every other node a value that is less than a certain pre-specified constant.

Let's take an example. The following is a table of weights where the row number and column number can be considered as node numbers.

```
6   15   25    4    6    1    4
15  28   19   20   15   28    6
25  19    4   26    2   10    2
4   20   26   15    1   15   29
6   15    2    1   13   20   15
1   28   10   15   12    5   16
4    6    2   29   15   16    7
```

Considering a weight limit of 15 the result I generated using my brute force solution looks like the following:

```
1  5  4
1  6  4
1  7  5  2
1  7  6
2  7  5  3
3  7  5
3  7  6
4  5
4  6
5  7
6  7
```

Now consider the first result `1 5 4` the weight between 1 and 5, w(1,5)=6; w(1,4) = 4; w(5,4) = 1. we can't add node 6 to this group because w(5,6) = 20.

The solution I have now takes forever when the dataset is larger. Is there an optimized algorithm that I am missing? Thanks for the help.

Comment: What determines whether-or-not a group of nodes satisfying the weight constraint is "unique"? ​ ​

Comment: there shouldn't be two groups with the same elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is the same as listing all cliques in a graph.

Given your weight matrix, construct a graph in which two vertices are connected if the weight between them is below the threshold. A clique in this graph is the same as the sets of vertices you are interested in.

A graph could contain exponentially many cliques - even exponentially many maximum cliques (consider for example $n/3$ paths of edge-length 2). So in general you will need exponential time to list all cliques.

Comment: Thanks! I was lost reading lot of other things like nearest neighbor, knn etc. when the problem was a graph one. After following your lead "groups of people who all know each other" seems to be the right simplification to the problem I stated :)

Comment: Looks like a branch and bound algorithm did me a good job in giving result better than an exponential time to generate a single maximum clique.